# How to make each Vue build include a version accessible in Vue app?

Tags: vue.js

In Vue, I'd like to be able to get the current build version. Preferably, it would be in YYYY-MM-DD-HH-MM format (the build time), rather than a random hash (which would be ok too).

Here's how someone did this
https://medium.com/@howitson/passing-generated-build-numbers-to-vue-app-f301e6b11877

Another idea:
have a bash script which updates .env file with a line VUE_APP_BUILD_VERSION=... (is there any utility for this?)
and then run `npm run build`

Any suggestions for simpler ways? Maybe get the .js file path and use that? `/js/app.5e716dd8.js`

Comment: You mean you want all the asset file names be suffixed with timestamps? Like, `app.2020-05-22-00-00.js`?

Comment: No, just be able to tell in Vue app scripts what build version is this app.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `npm version patch` in your build script, and get the version number from `package.json`.

Comment: This is actually pretty f**** cool man. ! Thanks! npm-version is quite versatile on how to set the version.. but just bumping it out so I can visually see its not cached works for me!